# Strange MySQL table sizes

Tags: mysql, indexing

I implemented an inverted index in MySQL using mainly these three tables:

```
WORDS (word_id, word)
INSTANCES (word_id, doc_id)
DOCUMENT (id, text)
```

where `word_id` is `INT` and `doc_id` is `BIGINT`

Then, I tried to de-normalize the WORDS and INSTANCES tables into one:

```
INSTANCES_NEW (word, doc_id)
```

where word is now `VARCHAR(50)` and `doc_id` is `BIGINT`

The tables INSTANCES and INSTANCES_NEW have both, two indexes for the `word_id/word` and `doc_id`. For the same data, INSTANCES is displayed as taking 146MB while the INSTANCES_NEW is displayed as taking 122.7MB. How can an `INT` take more space than `VARCHAR(50)`? Nearly all words take at least 3 characters - so theoretically the space taken should be more than doubled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult without knowing your data, but probably there is a difference in size of your indexes. As you said, you have different indexes for those tables...for the first one you have index on word_id/word and for the second one you have word/doc_id. So your indexes have different number of entries and most likely have different size. You can execute [SHOW TABLE STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html) to get a better idea (and probably post it here so we can analyze it together).

EDIT:
So, your results are:

**instances**

Total rows: 1348741

Average row length: 40B

Data: 52.57MB

Index: 93.20MB

Total: 145.77MB

**instances_new**

Total rows: 1383266

Average row length: 42B

Data: 56.57MB

Index: 66.14MB

Total: 122.71MB

and as you can see, your index for instances table (99.2MB) is quite larger than in the second case (66.14MB), while data is almost the same size. So as I supposed, difference in size comes from index size, while this small difference in data size can be explained by small difference in number of rows (approx.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here's a SHOW TABLE STATUS result:
[link](http://pastebin.com/SFMgrVL8)

Comment: This is very interesting. Why is the index smaller for strings rather than for integers?

Comment: Can you tell me what your indexes are? If I understand well, you don't have indexes on integer and string, but composite indexes on two columns...

Comment: No, I have two separate indexes for the fields, and not composite.

Comment: Again, it really depends on your data. For example, if you have word "my_word" in the 'word' column in all your records then you can guess that index size on this column will be quite small (and useless). Index size doesn't really depend on data type size as it depends on index cardinality. It also depends on index type. Database indexes are quite complex subject, you can start from here ;) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database)

Answer (score 1):

int is 4 bytes, varchar size depends on the character encoding. If it is a single-byte encoding, a 3-character word only takes 3 bytes. That size difference looks about right.

Comment: I am using UTF-8 as the character encoding so every character should take 4-bytes.